# Conditional CSS Class In Haml Coffee Template

Tags: css, hamlc

Give the following code in a .hamlc template:

```
.myDiv
  some content here
```

What if I wanted to add the class "special" to the div.myDiv based on a property of the model passed to the template.

so if is_special property of the model was true, the output would be what is shown below:

```
<div class="myDiv special">
   some content here
</div>
```

and if is_special was false, the output would be:

```
<div class="myDiv">
  some content here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class attribute:

```
.myDiv{ class: 'hoho' }
  some content here
```

which will result in:

```
<div class='hoho myDiv'>
  some content here
</div>
```

Now you can add some CoffeeScript code to the attribute to make it dynamic:

```
.myDiv{ class: @model.get('status') }
  some content here
```